# How to create USER roles/permissions with MongoDB and Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, user-permissions, user-roles

I have multiple **Users** in my MongoDB *database* and I want to create permissons/roles.
Lets say if i have the permisson/role: **Admin** - only than I can see *"a blue colored button or whatever else on the **website**"* but **only** if I have the right permissions for that.

So the point is, I dont know, how to set up roles and give my already existing **Users** in my *database* specific roles.

I would be very happy if someone could help me to clear this question up.

Comment: If you have Users on your database you could add a property roles to it or create a new collections with the roles. That's one step. Second step would be to fetch the user from your db and control the access in your application. Take a look here: http://lvtutorial.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-mongodb-crud-users-roles.html

Comment: Hi, Take a look at the ACL package: https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the link below, Its an official doc by MongoDB for ACL ( Access control list).

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authorization/

And its npm package built for MongoDB ACL,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/acl-mongodb